# API not returning auto generated ID

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

Am working on Symfony API Platform, to add and retrieve something. Table has two fields id and title.
But when i run the GET query the API is returning title only not id.

How to return ID too?

My Annotation:-

```
 * @ORM\Table(
*      name="school",
* @ApiResource(
*     attributes={
*         "order"={"title": "ASC"},
*         "normalization_context"={"groups"={"school.read"}, 
"enable_max_depth"=true},
*     },
*     itemOperations={
*         "get",
*         "put"
*     },
*     collectionOperations={
*          "get"={
*              "normalization_context"={
*                  "groups"={"school.read"}
*              }
*          }
*     },
*     normalizationContext={
*          "groups"={"school.read"}
*     },
*     denormalizationContext={
*          "groups"={"school.write"}
*     }
* )
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Eqsgroup\Repository\SchoolRepository")
* @UniqueEntity(
*      "title",
*      repositoryMethod="findByUniqueCriteria",
*      message="School already exists."
* )
*/
```

This is the Entity class

```
class School 
 {

/**
 * @var string the id of this School
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="guid", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
 * @Groups({"school.read, school.write"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string The title of the school
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="school should not be empty")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="school should not be empty")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 1,
 *      max = 250,
 *      minMessage = "length.min,{{ limit }}",
 *      maxMessage = "length.max,{{ limit }}"
 * )
 * @Groups({"school.read", "school.write"})
 */
private $title;

public function __construct(){ }

public function getId(): ?string
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle(string $title): self
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}
```

This is the output am currently getting:

```
[
{
 "title": "Test"
},
{
 "title": "Test2"
},
```

]

The expected output will include the auto generated is along with title.

Comment: Did you add the group `school.read` to the id field ? Could you show us the entire Entity please

Comment: No, how to add it?i will update the quesiton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the @Groups to allow Apli-Platform to read each field you want like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Groups({"school.read", "school.write"})
 */
private $id;
```

Have a look to the documentation here :
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#the-serialization-context-groups-and-relations

Comment: yes, i have added this already, the id is generated and updated in DB i can see it! :)

Comment: If the output isn't the one you take on the Api-Platform backoffice, add `school.write` to the ID so like this : `@Groups({"school.read", "school.write"})`

Comment: Hum, try to add the @Groups directly on the getter to be sure, if still not working I think it should be related with the @UniqueEntity. Try :
`/** @Groups({"school.read", "school.write"})
 */
public function getId(): ?string
{
    return $this->id;
} `

Comment: Yes Thanks! :) ,this was the issue we should add the groups to getter too! is adding to getter is mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure which attributes you want to expose ?

If not, configure it in the **yaml** of your entity :

```
# I don't know the path to your entity, just modify what you need to
XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\School:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
        title:
            expose: true
```